# Search item in a list and replace it with different value

Tags: python, list

I am trying to search a 3D list for an item, and if it is in there: replace it

```
winner =["Player", 100]
def leaderboardsave(winner):
    fileCSV = open('scores.csv')
    dataCSV = csv.reader(fileCSV)
    playersScores = list(dataCSV)
    winnerName = winner[0]
    if winnerName in playersScores:
        #replace item in playerScores with winner
    else:
        playersScores.append(winner)
        print(playersScores)
leaderboardsave(winner)
```

if winnername is playerScores already, i want to replace their score with the one stored in winner
My CSV is structured like this:

```
Owen, 20
George, 40
Lucas, 30
Jeremy, 60
```

Comment: Do you want to add it to the actual CSV file, or just to the in-memory list?

Comment: @JohnGordon Itll be added to the in-memory list for further data handling later in the program. After this, ill re-write it to the CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this inside your `if` conditions:

```
playersScores[playersScores.index(winnerName)] = winner
```

Here `playersScores.index(winnerName)` will return the index of `winner` in `playersScores` list. And then you can use that index for the assignment.

You can update your logical condition as:

```
try:
    winner_index = playersScores.index(winnerName) 
    playersScores[winner_index] = winner
except ValueError:  # Will raise this exception if "winnerName" 
                    # is not found in the list.
    playersScores.append(winner)
```

Edit:

In your last edit, since you mentioned `playersScores` is a list of tuples, you need to update `.index` call as:

```
playersScores = [['Player', ' 20'], ['Player2', ' 40'], ['Player3', ' 30'], ['Player4', ' 60'], ['Player', 100]]

player_name_list = zip(*playersScores)[0]  # list with all elements at index `0` 
winner_index = player_name_list.index(winnerName)
```

Comment: maybe call `index` before `if`, and use it in `if`, too. So, the list will be iterated once.

Comment: @burkay agreed. i was already updating the answer while you comment. in that case it's better to use `list.find()`

Comment: `index` throws `ValueError` when item is not in the list. `find` seems to be better :)

Comment: @burkay I tried the second solution, and it returned: ```'list' object has no attribute 'find'```
Also, i have edited my original post to show how my CSV is structured, would this still work?

Comment: @Zenot1c I am not much familiar with Python. I could not find the `find` function, either. I guess you better go with `index` function and wrap it around a try/catch block. @MoinuddinQuadri please edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zenot1c @burkay Sorry, it was my bad. `.find` exists in `string` but not in `list`. Updated my answer now

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I have included your suggestion, but when i `print(PlayersScores)` it returns`[['Player', ' 20'], ['Player2', ' 40'], ['Player3', ' 30'], ['Player4', ' 60'], ['Player', 100]]`. This means Index couldn't find `Player` in the List, yet it is there?

Comment: @Zenot1c My answer was based on the details you shared earlier. Updated it based on info given that you have list of tuples. Hope this helps.
If you want to change the question again with different details, it's better to post it as separate question. I might not be able to keep updating my answer. Hope you understand.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadi sorry, my mistake, im new to SO as a whole. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Zenot1c if this answer helped you, you can [upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) by clicking up arrow on the left. It will help me with 10 reputation gain.